# how to re-run java (UI automator/python) script recorded using culebra tester

Tags: github, adb, dump, android-uiautomator, androidviewclient

I have python 2.7, android view client, adb environment setup in my PC. Also I have connected my android device with culebra tester installed in it and performed some Test case steps to record script (Java/python). Now I have the recorded script ready. Can any one tell me the right procedure to re-run the recorded script in the same android device automatically, because culebra tester doesn't have any option to re-run the test case. Any inputs would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have generated your test script (*if you selected python as the code generation language*), you download it, rename it (*it is downloaded as .py.txt to avoid browser warnings*) and then you can run it as any other [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) script.

You need `python` and `androidviewclient` installed via `pip` or `easy_install`.

If you generated `java` code, then you copy or paste the code to your **Android Studio** project, create the APK, install and run.

Comment: Thanks for answering, 
I tried rerunning python script on the connected device using python IDLE after including the following code snippet
`from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit() vc = ViewClient(device=device, serialno=serialno)`
Following error is seen:
        `Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\joshuaji\Desktop\My idea- automation\CMIcrash.py", line 27, in
    from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'com'`
Can you help

Comment: check the [wiki](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki#microsoft-windows) it may help you with Windows installation

Comment: After setup, tried running the script, following error is thrown `Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:\Users\joshuaji\CMIcrash.py", line 31, in <module> pkg_resources.require('androidviewclient>=12.4.0')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 888, in require needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 774, in resolve raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
DistributionNotFound: The 'matplotlib' distribution was not found and is required by androidviewclient.` Kindly help

Comment: The above solution only clears the last error in line 774. but I am seeing a different error in the same line `DistributionNotFound: The 'requests' distribution was not found and is required by androidviewclient`. Also in the third last comment can you help to solve error in line 31 and line 888 as they are still unresolved?